# Desenvolvimento de um Sistema de Alarme Distribuido

Tags: java

O meu professor passou um trabalho para desenvolvermos uma ferramenta de alarme, botão de panico, mais ou menos. Onde um computador (cliente) irá acionar o botão e um outro computador (servidor) irá receber a notificação e irá dispará uma sirene. Só que ele disse que não queria como arquitetura cliente servidor, ele queria uma arquitetura distribuida. Não consegui entender, é possível fazer esse programa com essa arquitetura? Alguém pode me dizer que caminho seguir usando java? Obrigado.

Comment: É possível fazer isso usando [**RMI**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/RMI) (Remote Method Invocation), [**aqui**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html) tem um exemplo com código, *cliente* e *servidor*, e [**aqui**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-138781.html) há um artigo sobre esse modelo. Bom proveito!

Comment: Valeu cara, vou dar uma olhada! Abraços.